# Python O365 auth_flow_type='credentials' leads to Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'messages'

Tags: python, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I changed my code fro auth_type "authorization" to "credentials" to get rid of the logon process.

But whatever I try, I run into Error Message: Resource not found for the segment 'messages'

I played around with azure permissions but without any progress.

```
import sys
import os

from O365 import Account,FileSystemTokenBackend

credentials = ('3c7adf9b-3126-45d9-8239-3a9a66dbaae3','J8Q8Q~--------------------------')

token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path=os.getcwd()+'/token_folder/', token_filename='my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='f3aaaf31-b8db-4e24-b8a3-----------',token_backend=token_backend)
if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')

    mailbox = account.mailbox(resource = 'wo----------------hotmail.onmicrosoft.com')

    messages = mailbox.get_messages(limit=1500)  

    for message in messages:
        print(message.subject)
```

Output:

[image]

Azure Settings 1

[image]

Azure Settings 2

[image]

Azure Settings 3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> From your error screenshot, I observed that your code is calling **wrong URL** that does not involve **`/users`** segment in it. This happens if you pass **invalid UPN** in mailbox parameter.

I registered one Azure AD application and added same **API permissions** as below:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment by passing **wrong UPN** without @, I too got **same error** as you:

```py
import sys
import os

from O365 import Account,FileSystemTokenBackend

credentials = ('32f13e70-1098-4d33-99a6-xxxxxxxxx','PuL8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path=os.getcwd()+'/token_folder/', token_filename='my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='2773f7fd-d343-4afe-8230-xxxxxxxxx',token_backend=token_backend)
if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')

    mailbox = account.mailbox('xxxxxrkM365xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com') #incorrect UPN

    messages = mailbox.get_messages(limit=1500)  

    for message in messages:
        print(message.subject)
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, make sure to pass **correct user principal name** in your code that calls **`/users`** endpoint in the URL.

When I ran the code again by modifying UPN, I got **response** with messages subject successfully like below:

```py
import sys
import os

from O365 import Account,FileSystemTokenBackend

credentials = ('32f13e70-1098-4d33-99a6-xxxxxxxxx','PuL8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path=os.getcwd()+'/token_folder/', token_filename='my_token.txt')
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='2773f7fd-d343-4afe-8230-xxxxxxxxx',token_backend=token_backend)
if account.authenticate():
    print('Authenticated!')

    mailbox = account.mailbox('xxxxxrk@M365xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com') #correct UPN

    messages = mailbox.get_messages(limit=1500)  

    for message in messages:
        print(message.subject)
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked in user's mailbox where messages subject is same:

[image]